# Customizing annotations pop up in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm building an app for iPhone in which I need to customize the poped up annotation whenever the user clicks on the pin. But the point is I don't wanna use the default annotation view and I have created my own UIView (customized UIView) and whenever the user clicks on a pin, that customized view would be loaded on top of the screen.

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of solutions to this.  Check out:

https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview for a nice project creating custom calloutViews.

Here has a nice writeup as well [here](http://nfarina.com/post/29883229869/callout-view).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but actually that's not what i'm looking for. As I already said, I don't want the default pop up menu that pops up when you tap on a pin, I wanna somehow replace the event that happens when you tap on a pin, with a subview (basically I wanna load the subview on top of the screen whenever you click on a pin)